# Tabs, View Controller and iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tabs

I'm trying to create an iOS App and I'd like to make a "tab based application". Inside one of those tabs, I need to insert a Photo Gallery (I've already created one using ViewController). Is it possible to incorporate the ViewController in one of the tab items?
I hope you understand me, I'm not a professional programmer and English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Do you mean you want a photo gallery to show when the user selects one of the tabs? Are you using a storyboard in your project?

Comment: Yes, I mean this and yes, I'm using a storyboard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/) your can see step-by-step tutorial for tabbed application. Also I would highly recommend watching "Developing for iOS" [Stanford course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522), they have detailed sample for tabbed applications too.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created your view controller with the photo gallery, all you need to do is select the controller, go to the Editor menu, and choose "Embed In", then "Tab Bar Controller".